# How to get "$.Post" variable in another site

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i search internet for my question and i doesn't found how to get my $_POST on another page. Please help.

game.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    ?>
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var drzewo = 0;

function save() {
    
        $.post( "save.php", { drzewo: drzewo } );
        window.location.href = "save.php"   
    
    }
```

presave.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
    session_start();

        $_SESSION['drewno'] = $_POST["drzewo"];
echo $_SESSION['drewno']

?>
```

[Undefined array key picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7cMs.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see where `save()` is executed in your code. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, in your image I see C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\clicker\presave.php not "save.php"

Comment: @twisty i change name and this is still doesn't work

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to pass data from one URL to another, use query string. `$.post()` makes a POST request, but it seems like `save.php` is not an endpoint but actually a page.

In other words, you can do this:

```
window.location.href = `save.php?drzewo=${drzewo}`;
```

And then on `save.php` simply read the value from `$_GET`:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['drewno'] = $_GET["drzewo"];
    echo $_SESSION['drewno']
?>
```

Comment: Thank  You its work!

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems incomplete in my opinion. There are many things missing from your question. From your image I assume you are using it on local server. There are one thing that looks weird is this:

```
`$.post( "save.php", { drzewo: drzewo } );`
```

Where is this save.php file stored? Is it stored in your root file? Or along with the operating file. Put a "/" before save.php and see what happens.
There is another thing that seems awkward is your image is showing there is a presave.php file. But I found nothing about that file in your question details.
I can see that you put a redirecting code in your script. JS is not supposed to work like that. What happening here is it is doing an asynchronous operation. That is why PHP can't get the data and showing you a error. If you want to send data send it in a form. Or you can put a redirection in your PHP code after getting the post data. Since it is an AJAX call you can see some reports in your console.log() with the response data.

Comment: Sorry i edited this $.post( "save.php", { drzewo: drzewo } ); turn to $.post( "presave.php", { drzewo: drzewo } ); but still doesn't work

Comment: @Johnyy If you edit something please edit it in your code too sothat we can see what you are doing in your code. Please edit the post as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post( "save.php", { drzewo: drzewo } );
window.location.href = "save.php"
```

Let's analyze these 2 lines of code.
When you send a post request through javascript, it goes through an ajax request and the browser waits till the `save.php` completes working it's code and returns to the ajax. Here the `save.php` has received the $_POST data and has processed it.

This processed data by `save.php` will not output in the browser. It will go to the post (ajax) callback function. If you want to display the data, you need to use a callback function. See this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp for a simple usage of `$.post()` function.

In the next line of your code you are redirecting your browser to `save.php` without sending any $_POST data. Since now your `save.php` does not have any information about `$_POST["drzewo"]` it throws an error `Undefined array key "drzewo"` .

Therefore instead of `window.location.href` page redirect, you need a callback function with your `$.post()` function. I hope now you understand why you are getting this error.

[Edit]- I have added some code for your better understanding. You can refer to this excellent "JQuery Ajax POST Method" tutorial from  freecodecamp.org. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/jquery-ajax-post-method/

game.php

```
<?php
session_start();    
?>

<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn" onclick="save();">Click this</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var drzewo = 0;

  function save() {
    $.post("save.php", {
        drzewo: drzewo
      },
      function(result) {
        alert("This result contains the output from save.php : " + result);
        //Write here the code you want to execute after the POST request is successfully completed.
      }
    );
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

save.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $_SESSION['drewno'] = $_POST["drzewo"];
  echo $_SESSION['drewno'];
```

Comment: I analyze code from w3schools.com and it is not shown how to call the function $.post